# Check connection details to SQL Server 2000/2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, database-connection

I want to migrate some DBs hosted on SQL 2000/2005 to SQL 2014, I don't have direct access to DBs and I want to know all applications connecting to it and connection details. Is there any best way to get this information? I tried using DB profiling but its not allowed as its taking up lot of space on hosted DB server which causing disruptions.

Any better way like an SQL statement or Remote connection monitoring will be helpful.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

To find out the names of processes that connect to the DB server in 2000/2005, you will need to run a job, probably every 30 seconds or even more often.  That job will have to store the results into a temp table and then add new process names and databases, and perhaps logins.  Here is a start:

Create a table to accumulate the information:

```
create table DBUsage_accumulate (
    [id] int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LoginName] SYSNAME NOT NULL,
    HostName SYSNAME NOT NULL,
    DBName SYSNAME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_DBUSAGE_ACCUMULATE PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id asc));
```

Then you need to have an unique constraint on this table, use an index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
    IX_ACCUMULATE_LOGIN_DB_HOST
on DBUsage_Accumulate
(
    LoginName asc
    ,HostName asc
    ,DBName asc
);
```

and now you need to periodically run a check on sp_who2:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_sp_who2
    (
      SPID INT,
      Status VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      [LoginName] SYSNAME NULL,
      HostName SYSNAME NULL,
      BlkBy SYSNAME NULL,
      DBName SYSNAME NULL,
      Command VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      CPUTime INT NULL,
      DiskIO INT NULL,
      LastBatch VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      ProgramName VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      SPID2 INT
      --,RequestID INT NULL --comment out for SQL 2000 databases
    )

INSERT  INTO #temp_sp_who2
EXEC sp_who2;

CREATE TABLE #temp_sp_who2
    (
      SPID INT,
      Status VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      [LoginName] SYSNAME NULL,
      HostName SYSNAME NULL,
      BlkBy SYSNAME NULL,
      DBName SYSNAME NULL,
      Command VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      CPUTime INT NULL,
      DiskIO INT NULL,
      LastBatch VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      ProgramName VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      SPID2 INT
      --,RequestID INT NULL --comment out for SQL 2000 databases
    )

INSERT  INTO #temp_sp_who2
EXEC sp_who2;

delete from #temp_sp_who2
where exists (
    select 1 from DBUsage_accumulate A
    where A.LoginName = #temp_sp_who2.Loginname
    and A.HostName = #temp_sp_who2.hostName
    and A.DBName = #temp_sp_who2.dbname);

insert into DBUsage_accumulate(LoginName,HostName,DBName)
select 
distinct 
    LoginName
    ,HostName
    ,dbname
from #temp_sp_who2
where [DBName] is not null
and [HostName] != '  .';
```

Placing the last chunk of SQL into a job that runs every 5-30 seconds will accumulate a list of all host names, DB names and logins.  You can use this to migrate the correct databases and logins as well as to amend connection strings in client machines.

Tested in 2000.

Comment: It took nearly 15 tries to get this answer into Stack Overflow!  the error message "an error occurred submitting the answer" is unhelpful.